# Interpretation of proof by contradiction

Tags: analysis, logic, proof-writing

If I derive ‘not-A’ from ‘A’, have I ‘proven “not-A” by contradiction’? Thank you.

Comment: Rather: can it be said that I have ‘proven “not-A” by contradiction’?

Comment: Is what I have done ‘proven “not-A” by contradiction’—or have I done something else altogether?

Comment: $A\Rightarrow\neg A$ would be a [proof by negation](http://math.andrej.com/2010/03/29/proof-of-negation-and-proof-by-contradiction/) which would prove $\neg A$; note that $A\Rightarrow\neg A$ is logically equivalent to $\neg A\lor\neg A\equiv\neg A$

Answer (score 3):

If you assume $A$ is true, and you show that this implies that not $A$ is true, then yes, you have arrived at a contradiction. Therefore, your assumption that $A$ is true is false, and it must be the case that not $A$ is true.

Answer (score 1):

No. You've assumed A and arrived at a contradiction (namely that A and "not A" are both true), so you've *disproved* A.

Answer (score 0):

The implication $A \Rightarrow \overline{A}$ is false when $A$ is true. So if you derive $\overline{A}$ from $A$ correctly, then you have proven that $A$ is false. Then $\overline{A}$ is necessary true.